# How to get text from TextInput in react-navigation 5

Tags: forms, react-native, react-navigation

I implemented form in navigation class and now I can not add constructor inside

const Screen = ({navigation}) => { … }  class.

```
    const ContactScreen = ({navigation}) => {
    
        constructor(props) {
            super(props)
            this.state = { email: '', number: '', note: '', }
        };
        
        buttonpress() {
            console.log(this.state.email);
            console.log(this.state.number);
            console.log(this.state.note);
        };
    
        return (
                <View style={styles.main}>
                    <ScrollView horizontal={false} showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false} style={{paddingTop: 20,}}>
                        <TextInput placeholder="Email" style={styles.viewform}
                            onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({email:text})} />
                        <TextInput secureTextEntry={true} placeholder="Mobile Number" style={styles.viewform}
                            onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({number:text})} />
                        <TextInput secureTextEntry={true} placeholder="Note" multiline style={styles.note}
                            onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({note:text})} />

                        <View style={styles.viewbutton}>
                            <Button onPress={() => this.buttonpress()} title="submit" color="#841584" style={styles.submit}/>
                        </View>
                    </ScrollView>
                </View>
        );}
```

But it show error and i don't know how to fix it.

```
        error: SyntaxError: E:\Shravan Variya\React Native\Learning\API\Api_Demo\src\screens\ContactScreen.js: Missing semicolon (8:22)

           6 | const ContactScreen = ({navigation}) => {
           7 |
        >  8 |     constructor(props) {
            |                       ^
          9 |         super(props)
         10 |         this.state = { email: '', number: '', note: '', }
         11 |     };
```

I'm new to react.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: error: SyntaxError: E:\Shravan Variya\React Native\Learning\API\Api_Demo\src\screens\ContactScreen.js: Missing semicolon (8:22)

const ContactScreen = ({navigation}) => {

     constructor(props) {
                      ^
        super(props)
        this.state = { email: '', number: '', note: '', }
     };

Comment: "Missing semicolon (8:22)" apparently you're missing a semi colon on line 8

Comment: we can not add semicolon there you can run this code.

Comment: well you're missing a semi colon somewhere, definitely worth getting a good linter setup that can catch these things for you and will tell you exactly where the problem is

Comment: what is above your declaration of ContactScreen on line 6?

Comment: it is react navigation 5.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think this is the way, i found the solution.
I'm using component class for this issue.

```
export default class ContactScreen extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = { email: '', number: '', note: '', }
    };
    
    buttonpress() {
        console.log(this.state.email);
        console.log(this.state.number);
        console.log(this.state.note);
    };
    
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.main}>
                <ScrollView horizontal={false} showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false} style={{paddingTop: 20,}}>
                    <TextInput placeholder="Email" style={styles.viewform}
                        onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({email:text})} />
                    <TextInput secureTextEntry={true} placeholder="Mobile Number" style={styles.viewform}
                        onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({number:text})} />
                    <TextInput secureTextEntry={true} placeholder="Note" multiline style={styles.note}
                        onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({note:text})} />

                    <View style={styles.viewbutton}>
                        <Button onPress={() => this.buttonpress()} title="submit" color="#841584" style={styles.submit}/>
                    </View>
                </ScrollView>
            </View>
        );
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

We cannot use the constructor In the functional component if you are supposed to use the state inside the component then you have to use the useState hook to store the data in the state and process it.

Or else you have to convert the whole component to the class component.

Check out the docs for more information.
https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

Answer (score 0):

You are using a functional component which means you cannot use a constructor. You need to make use of hooks in a functional component. In your case useState is what's needed to change your state. See example below.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
const ContactScreen = ({ navigation }) => {

    const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
    const [number, setNumber] = useState('');
    const [note, setNote] = useState('');
    

    const buttonpress = () => {
        console.log(email);
        console.log(number);
        console.log(note);
    };

    return (
        <View style={styles.main}>
            <ScrollView horizontal={false} showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false} style={{ paddingTop: 20, }}>
                <TextInput placeholder="Email" style={styles.viewform}
                    onChangeText={setEmail} />
                <TextInput secureTextEntry={true} placeholder="Mobile Number" style={styles.viewform}
                    onChangeText={setNumber} />
                <TextInput secureTextEntry={true} placeholder="Note" multiline style={styles.note}
                    onChangeText={setNote} />

                <View style={styles.viewbutton}>
                    <Button onPress={() => buttonpress()} title="submit" color="#841584" style={styles.submit} />
                </View>
            </ScrollView>
        </View>
    );
}
```